# Does difficulty scale for multiple players in Lethal Company?

Tags: lethal-company

Does Lethal Company scale the difficulty level based on the number of people playing? Do things like the required quota change if you have 2 players instead of 4 players?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quota doesn't seem to be impacted by the number of players in the game.  [The game wiki](https://lethal-company.fandom.com/wiki/Profit_Quota#Quota_Calculation) has an explanation and what the formula is behind it:

> The formula for quota increase is a quadratic function, meaning the quota increase rises with every quota fulfilled. Additionally, the quota increase is multiplied by an evaluated curve value in the interval `[-0.5; 0.5]`, with a random decimal between 0 and 1 as input to randomize the quota
>
> [image: randomize curve]
>
> ```
> nextProfitQuotaIncrease = 100 * (1 + timesFulfilled² / 16) *
> (randomizerCurve.eval(random(0, 1)) + 1)
> ```

As far as other elements to the games "difficulty", I haven't been able to find anything definitive saying player count impacts the difficulty in any way (i.e. [altering spawn rates](https://lethal-company.fandom.com/wiki/Mechanics#Spawning_requirements) of monsters, etc.).